# In native German words, is Q always followed by U, as in English?

Tags: spelling

In English, native words with a Q always have a U immediately after it. (There are some borrowed words like "faqir" from Arabic that do not follow this pattern.)

I am starting to learn German. Every word with a Q that I have seen so far follows this convention, but the sources I have been using have not mentioned a rule like this. I remember this rule being mentioned explicitly when learning English grammar. Is this a rule in German?

Comment: Most English words with *qu* are not native.

Comment: You mean they were absorbed from romance languages over the centuries? But not in as modern of times as "Qi"?

Comment: `grep -ie 'q[^u]' /usr/share/dict/ngerman #=> MySQL, SQL, qm, qmm`.

Comment: Hah regex, there's a language I do understand!

Comment: Headwords with initial Q are so few you can count them by hand in the dict. Headwords with medial Q might mostly reflect qu-roots. Those that don't have a root in the lexicon might be interesting.

Comment: @JamesFaix: Sorry, that should have been `grep -iE 'q([^u]|$)' /usr/share/dict/ngerman #=> Compaq, FAQ, FAQs, ICQ, IQ, IRQ, Nasdaq, SQL, qm, qmm`

Comment: @DavidVogt Isn't that a more or less meaningless statement? If you go back far enough or change your parameters enough, *no words* are "native English". But you know what OP means, surely? He means words that aren't considered loan words *in the current day*. Let's not be pedantic for no good reason.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Latin, <qu> is a [digraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraph_(orthography)) used to represent the labiovelar stop [kʷ]. The spelling entered English via Latin and French. Native words with [kw] used to be spelled <cw>, e.g. *cwēn* "queen", but <qu> took over. Note that in some cases, English <qu> is pronounced [k] as in Modern French, e.g. *antique* (and others ending in *-que*).

The letter <q> is also used in the [romanisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization) of words from other languages.
This is a productive source for new words containing <q> not followed by <u>. Wikipedia has [some English examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_containing_Q_not_followed_by_U), but the same holds true for German in principle (but see the last paragraph).

Two examples:

- [Transliterated Mandarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinyin): *qi*. The Mandarin pronunciation of <q> apparently is [tɕʰ], for which native speakers of English can substitute [tʃ].
- [Transliterated Arabic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Arabic): *niqab*, where <q> stands for IPA [q], for which English speakers substitute [k].

In short: Words that contain <q> have different sources, and the pronunciation varies accordingly. The observation that <q> is almost always followed by <u> in English is derived from the status of  <qu> as a digraph in Latin and the abundance of loan words from Latin and French.

One difference between English and German is that in Old High German, [kw] was always spelled in the Latin manner as <qu> and not <cw> as in Old English. Native [kw] seems rare. In the example of OHG *queman*, it became [k] (NHG *kommen*), whereas it was retained as [kv] in *quellen*, *quälen*, *(er)quicken*.

Furthermore, German prefers nativised spellings over transliterations. For instance, where English uses *Quran*, German has *Koran*. This can lead to funny juxtapositions such as that between nativised *Burka* and [transliterated](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_31635) *Niqab* in [this news article](http://www.general-anzeiger-bonn.de/bonn/stadt-bonn/OB-Sridharan-l%C3%B6st-Diskussion-%C3%BCber-Vollverschleierung-aus-article4032774.html).

Comment: the list of _english_ words is just in case the TO likes to see the similarity (and loanwords [candidates] in German) since both English and German have Latin roots? Or because the TO sets it like a fact that English requires the u?

Comment: To show that romanisation is a productive source of words with *q* not followed by *u* (and because it shows some other source languages besides Mandarin and Arabic).

Comment: "Qatar" is typically spelt ["Katar"](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Katar) in German, as far as I can tell. Maybe pick another example that also works in German, given that we're on [german.se], and the examples are supposed to be examples of the statement "the same holds true for German"?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper And “qi” is often spelled [“Chi”](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Qi), despite the Wikipedia article using the spelling “Qi”. In fact, Duden also recommends the spelling “Qi” but this must be a recent development, and the German *pronunciation* is incompatible with this spelling (it’s pronounced [ˈt͡ʃiː] or [tɕʰi˥˩], *not* [ki]). It’s therefore probably bogus/an anglicism.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Die Schreibung mit *q* entspricht der [Pinyin](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinyin)-Umschrift. Eine solche Umschrift erlaubt es denen, die mit ihr vertraut sind, die Aussprache korrekt wiederzugeben. Am Ende ist das nichts anderes als wenn man gelernt hat, *bruschetta* und *Marquis* richtig auszusprechen.

Comment: @DavidVogt Danke. Mir war nicht bekannt, dass der Gebrauch von Pinyin für deutsche Transliteration üblich ist. Der Fakt, dass es zwar eine ISO aber (soweit ich sehen kann) keine DIN ist, legt nahe, dass dies auch nicht der Fall ist.

Comment: Interessanter Text, aber ich verstehe nicht, warum es als Antwort akzeptiert wurde. Die Frage war doch: "Is this a rule in German?" - gibt es eine Regel im _Deutschen_, daß auf "q" immer ein "u" folgt. Was denn nun, gibt es sie oder nicht?

Comment: @SteffenRoller Wir haben zwei Beobachtungen: Zum einen hat <qu> einen besonderen Status aufgrund des Lateinischen; zum anderen gibt es <q> ohne folgendes <u> in Umschriften. Diese Beobachtungen könnte man zwar auf ein Ja oder Nein verkürzen (wahrscheinlich je nachdem, ob man Umschrift ausschließen möchte); aber was wäre dadurch gewonnen?

Comment: @DavidVogt Gewonnen wäre damit, daß die ursprüngliche Frage beantwortet wäre. Ich bin kein Troll sondern ernsthaft an der Antwort interessiert. Wenn ich den Text und die Kommentare korrekt interpretiere, komme ich zu folgendem Schluß: Ja, im Deutschen folgt auf ein 'q' immer ein 'u' - außer es handelt sich um Umschriften aus anderen Sprachen, das wäre nach meiner Auffassung dann aber nicht mehr "im Deutschen". Da der OP davon spricht, daß er Deutsch lernt, wäre das die Antwort, die ihm die größte Hilfe gibt. Wäre das korrekt?

Answer (score 20):

My Database of German words contains 2174 words with *Q* or *q* followed by *u*, but only 2 where after *Q* or *q* comes some other letter. There is no word that ends with *q*. The two exceptional words are:

> - Qi (Chinese origin)
> - Maqam (Arab origin)

I hope this answers your question.

---

**addendum** (reaction to comments)

When I read the word *»Qi«* for the first time I pronounced it as [ki], but the correct pronunciation is [t͡ʃiː]. If it were a German word, [ki] would be written as *»Ki«*, but [t͡ʃiː] would be spelled *»Tschie«*.

In most cases when there is a foreign or artificial word that contains the letter q not followed by u, it is spelled as [k]: Al-Qaida = [alˈka​ɪda], Uniqa (an Austrian Insurance company) = [ˈunika]. *Qi* and compounds containing *Qi* (*Qigong*) are the only exception.

Comment: I would be hard pressed to accept these as native German words.

Comment: @Chieron Where in the answer does it say "native"?

Comment: @Chieron, it has a nativized pronounciation, /xi:/ (and thus also transliterated *Xi*, not to be confused with the Greek Letter)). That makes it native in a way.

Comment: @sgf it says so in the question.

Comment: @vectory Neither word (resp. spelling variant) is localized so far that they would "follow a spelling convention" (*Maqam* should be germanized as *Makam*, *Qi* is harder to localize, *Schi* would look weird, *Chi* would preserve the ambiguity)

Comment: @Chieron https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Maqam, https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Qi. Also note https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Qigongkugel which definitely is not a term known to non-German speakers...

Comment: @Alexander These words are not germanized, instead they are Fremdwörter which do not yet follow standard spelling rules. But the question is about such rules, so the examples are not entirely valid. Inclusion in the Duden is **not sufficient** to make a word *native*. Particularly, if the localization hasn't progressed so far. The current spelling is the English one.

Comment: @Alexander I’m doubtful of the Duden references since the German pronunciation is incompatible with this spelling and it’s nonstandard transliteration. Furthermore, I believe the preferred spelling used to be “Chi”. “Qi” probably an anglicism, and I wouldn’t hold my breath that the current Duden entry won’t be corrected back to “Chi” in future editions.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar That's not a word. Tahdig is the correct spelling.

Comment: @VahidAmiri I found the word "Tadiq" also, that's why I wrote. If you say that this is not the way it is spelt, please consider my comment obsolete. I removed it already.

Answer (score 10):

For a long time, the same rule "Q is always followed by u" was true for German as well. However, in mean time, the de facto defining book for the German language, the Duden added the words "Qi" (Chi), "Qi­gong", "Qi­gong­ku­gel" and "Qin­dar" (and abbreviations and words derived from abbreviations, like "QR-Code" for which no "real" German word exists)

Comment: The terminus technicus you are looking for is "phonotactical rule of German".

Comment: jonathan.scholbach How is this phonotactical? It's about letters, not sounds.

Answer (score 9):

The same rule as in English applies to German: Q is always followed by u. In many children's school books, the letter is really mentioned as "Qu".

Also, the same as in English holds, that there are loanwords and transcriptions from other languages where Q is *not* followed by u. This is true for example for words of Chinese or Arabic origin. As others have mentioned, the Chinese word *Qi* (living energy in Daoism) is among the most used of them, which my also be transcribed as "Chi".

Answer (score -2):

From a statistical point of view necessarily. But there are no rules without exception. For example, with abbreviations such as QM.

Comment: Abbreviations are not words.

Comment: thats true. . .